# Get current category id from post page wordpress

Tags: posts, categories

I have a problem to get category id of current post. We are using `<?php get_the_category( $id ) ?>` for finding out category of current post.
If a post like 'demo' has 2 category like cat1 and cat2. When i open a cat1 page and then go to demo page, i want different layout.. and when i open a cat2 page and then go to demo page, i want to open this demo page with other layout. It can be only done when i will identify.. from which post has called.. but how??

Comment: I don't know if you ever got this solved, but I just finished writing a very extensive post navigation function for this, also check out the answer from @G.M. to my original question [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/170007/31545). You can, stripping the code from both answers and combining it, know from which category the single post came from and then use the `single_template` filter to set a specific template

Answer (score 1):

WordPress has a function [`wp_get_referer`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_referer), which gets the referring url from the http-header. So, if you go from a category archive to a single post, the name of the category will normally be included in that url. This means you can start your `single.php` like this:

```
$refer = wp_get_referer();
if (strpos($refer, 'category/cat1') != false) {... do something ...}
elseif (strpos($refer, 'category/cat2') != false) {... do something else ...}
else {... do a default thing ...}
```

Depending on your setup this solution may need some tweaking, but the general idea is clear, I hope.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $categories = get_the_category( $post->ID ); ?>
```

This will return an array of categories, which you can get the id from, like so:

```
$categories[0]-> term_id;
```

This will be for the first category in the array if there is more than one.

Information on usage can be found in the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category)

Comment: Thanks,for this information. But i need a category from which post has called rather than first category.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't quite understand, what do you mean by 'which post has called'?

Comment: Simply-- there is a category page for cat-1 and its display all its post i.e demo. when i open demo from this page i want to open demo post in layout-1. and if i open demo post from cat-2 category page then it must be open with layout-2.

Comment: I can do this using query string but i don't want to use this due to url issue.

Comment: I would suggest either setting the category as post data using either a form (though that's unsemantic) or javascript - though that won't work with javascript, at least it will gracefully degrade.

You might also want to rephrase your question to better reflect what you want - changing a posts layout depending on what category is was visited from - as you'll be more likely to get answers.

Comment: Layout of post that a post look in this format(just looks) or another format.. If i use javascript then its also place query string in url.

Comment: The only other thing I can think to suggest is using session variables to temporarily save the category page that was last visited, and then if the currently viewed post is in that category change the layout.

Comment: Thanks, for reply and suggestion. But can this be possible using some wordpress tricks rather than php.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Gaffen : "changing a posts layout depending on what category is was visited from"

First on the category template page in your theme (i.e. category.php)

get the category id and store it in the WordPress Transient option.

```
global $wp_query;

//get category id (or name, slug) and store to the transient api
$categoryId = $wp_query->queried_object->cat_ID;
set_transient( 'category_id_visited', $categoryId, 1 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS );
```

now on single.php or the single post display template page.

get the value from Transient and change display acccordingly

```
if ( false === ( $category_id_visited = get_transient( 'category_id_visited' ) ) ) {
    // this code runs when there is no valid transient set
    //do nothing for now
} else {
    echo 'You came by visiting category: ' . $category_id_visited;
    //delete transient if required, otherwise it will be expired automatically
    delete_transient( 'category_id_visited' );
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your single.php you could use for example

```
if(has_category('layout-1')) {
  // do layout-1-category stuff here
} elseif (has_category('layout-2')) {
  // layout-2 stuff here
} else {
  // stuff for all the other styles/regular stuff
}
```

Better yet, use [get_template_part](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) so you don't just flood your single.php with all kinds of silly code.

Answer (score 0):

First get category ID:

```
$cat_id = get_queried_object_id();
```

Then get category name:

```
$cat_name = get_cat_name($cat_id)
```

Then you can decide depending on category name what to do:

```
if ($cat_name == 'Cat 1') {
   // ... url = layout-1
} elseif ($cat_name == 'Cat 2') {
   // ... url = layout-2
}
```

Comment: ```$cat_id = get_queried_object_id();``` will retrive the post ID and NOT the category ID when you are on a post page, like the OP asked.