# Check if redirected from a specific page template

Tags: theme-development, redirect, wp-redirect

I have a page template, which redirects to the homepage using this:

```
wp_redirect( home_url() );
```

Now, on the homepage is it possible to check if it has been redirected from a specific page template **without** knowing the URL of that page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get default permalink structure from pretty URL's](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/170007/get-default-permalink-structure-from-pretty-urls)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` to check the page where it redirected from

You can use it as below.

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == "path-of-page-you-want-to-check"){
//Do something here
}
```

Conditionally you can call functions like `is_home()`, `is_front_page()` to run that block of code in homepage only

Comment: Just a tip on your formatting, don't add function names or short pieces of code in bold, use backticks or codeblock. Also, your method is not really reliable, although it will work in most cases, check [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/170007/31545) for a workaround :-)

Comment: My pleasure. Quick is not always preferable, reliable is. Always good to know alternatives :-). Enjoy