# Pass variable to next page

Tags: variables

I'm putting simple breadcrumbs in a site, based on a custom post's category.

Items > Category > Individual Post

"Items" doesn't change, it's just plain text.

In the Category page it's title is coded like this.

```
$term = $wp_query->queried_object;
$cat_title = $term->name;
```

An Individual post can have more than one category so I need to keep a track of which category the user clicked through to get to a detail page.

What's the best way to pass $cat_title and it's slug (to make the URL) to a detail page?

In the case where a user does a search and goes directly to a detail page, I assume I can check if this title is set, if not then I pull the first category it belongs to.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get default permalink structure from pretty URL's](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/170007/get-default-permalink-structure-from-pretty-urls)

Comment: That helps. While I knew there were several questions that might answer my question I didn't know which was best. That looks like a very simple answer. 

What do I do with this question now that a comment has answered it?

Comment: use php session.it should works