# Previous page or reffer url in worpress

Tags: references

Is there any method to get the previous page /refer page url in wordpress.

In my wordpress site there is a paypal form it include return url . So after payment complete it come back to the site. Now i need to check this page is returned from paypal website, not the user manually taken this page.

How to check this? Is there any function?

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can use [this approach](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/192018/31545). There are also some valuable links you need to check out in the linked post. The method described in the linked post is far more reliable than `wp_get_referer()` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
wp_get_referer()
```

function will give you a referrer page URL.
[codex documentation here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_referer)

Comment: You know this is extremely unreliable. It will not work if referers on client side is disabled or when a client is behind a proxy

Comment: The REFERER is sent by the client's browser as part of the HTTP protocol and is, therefore, unreliable indeed. But @ron r wants the referrer URL just to check that direct access of a page.

Comment: but not working when it is redirected from palypal .It work within the site.