# How can i ensure that SQL statements are not displayed if an enduser types the wrong variable name in the URL

Tags: url-rewriting, security

My question is similar to [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/221647/passing-variable-as-url-parameter-security-concerns). It is about security of my wordpress site which has custom pages that call variables on the url.

An example of my url looks like this:

```
https://mysitevvv.ke/mysite1/publications/?pages=getabstract&pubid=3371
```

My problem/concern is that if an enduser changes the parameter `pubid` to `pbid` or any other random non-existent variable name other that `pubid` wordpress returns the SQL query on the back end like so:

**WordPress database error:** [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1]
`SELECT * FROM wp7m_refs WHERE id =`

How can i secure my site to protect against this? Can [add_query_arg( $args )](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/) function protect against this and if yes, how?

Comment: you should always validate input, all input regardless how you get it and regardless of what you do with it. The is always true whatever software you are developing

Comment: In addition to Mark's comment: in a production environment you should never output any errors (except for custom ones) to the user.

Comment: Granted Mark...Are you suggesting if i validate my url then wordpress will not return the sql statements in the backend?

Comment: @AlexMaina that code obviously do not validate input. It is not a wordpress code and if it is not your code I would just not use it until the developer fixes it

Comment: Thank you @MarkKaplun. Unfortunately i cannot upvote your comment due to lack of enough privilege. Consider this reply as an upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two separate problems here:

1. You have code that causes an error.
2. That error is exposing information to end users that you don't want to expose.

The problem that's causing #2 is that you have error printing enabled in a production environment, which is against best practice. Error reporting is controlled by [a PHP configuration parameter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting). This doesn't involve WordPress and your host should be able to help with this. However keep in mind that if you do not have a staging or testing environment you would be unaware of any errors that are occurring. So make sure that your errors are at least being logged somewhere that you can check.

The problem that's causing #1 in the first place is that your site's code is apparently taking the value of the `pubid` parameter and putting it directly into an SQL query. This is a **major security problem**. I cannot understate the severity of this issue. If this is a production site *you should remove the code that's responsible for this feature immediately*. If you don't know how to do this, and if you have user's personal data in your database, then you need to take your site offline.

In your example `pubid` is a number. Therefore in your code when you access `$_GET['pubid']` you need to include code that makes sure that this value is a number. If it is not a number then you should not run the query at all. For example, using WordPress's [`absint()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/absint/) function:

```
if ( ! isset( $_GET['pubid'] ) ) {
    return;
}

$pubid = absint( $_GET['pubid'] );

if ( ! $pubid ) {
    return;
}

// Perform query.
```

The important thing is that you should never accept external data and use it in an SQL query without first making sure that the value is safe and valid. Not doing so leaves you vulnerable to 'SQL injection' attacks.

In your query you should also be making using of [`$wpdb->prepare()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/) to safely insert values into an SQL statement.

Comment: I see this `absint` thing all over in core, this is just very wrong even if it blocks the obvious attack vectors. The right thing is to use `filter_var` to validate the value is positive int and convert the type

Comment: Thank you @JacobPeattie for the insightful answer